# Listview - inflate new view on click

Tags: android

I have a listview in which each view contains the summary of a topic, along with a few other pieces of data. When the user clicks one of the items, I want to inflate a new view that contains the summary as well as the full text of the question, plus a few new pieces of data. I would like this to display inside the current listview, not launch a new activity. How could I go about doing this?

Edit: I'm thinking that one way to do this would be, rather than creating/inflating a new view, to put all of the elements in the initial view but set some of them to invisible initially. Then I can program the OnClickListener to set those items visible. My question, then, is how to get access to the items in each view?

Answer (score 1):

As per I understood your question I would like to advise you that you should use expandable list view. and put your description or extra information as a child of each group.

you will find example of expandable list view. [Here](http://android-adda.blogspot.in/2011/06/custom-expandable-listview.html)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for suggesting the expandable list view - it's a good idea and I'll probably use it in the future. However, for this situation, I think my solution of loading all the elements into a single view and setting some of them invisible until clicked works best. Rather than adding an OnItemClickedListener to the ListView, I added OnClickListeners to the views themselves in the adapter's getView method. Seems to work perfectly for now, however I'd be open to thoughts about doing it this way /other suggestions.